# Arboles Binarios con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo que crear un árbol binario con tkinter. Tengo un codigo para crear el árbol binario AVL pero también tengo que "Graficar con tkinter" ya busque y no puedo

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra tu código

Answer (score 0):

Para este fin puedes usar [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) con el paquete [pygraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation.html). Existe un método que puedes usar para exportar el gráfico y una vez exportado cargas la imagen en tkinter. Te recomiendo [este tutorial](http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/) para saber como generar los gráficos y exportarlos.

Comment: Para que la respuesta tenga mayor posibilidad de ser aceptada pon un ejemplo con código